Navbar with Toggle Button Using Bootstrap 5 not working
I'm working on a web project where I need to implement a responsive sidebar that can be toggled using a button in the navbar.
I'm using Bootstrap for the layout, and I've encountered some difficulties in achieving this functionality. The sidebar should be hidden by default on mobile devices and only displayed when the user clicks on a menu button in the navbar. On larger screens, the sidebar should be visible without any additional interaction. I've tried using media queries in CSS to control the visibility of the sidebar based on screen size, and I've implemented JavaScript functionality to toggle the sidebar when the menu icon in the navbar is clicked. However, when I clicks on menu icon, the sidebar is not display.
Could someone please provide guidance on how to properly implement this responsive sidebar feature using Bootstrap 5?


function toggleSidebar() {
  var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
  if (sidebar.classList.contains('show')) {
    sidebar.classList.remove('show');
  } else {
    sidebar.classList.add('show');
  }
}
.sidebar {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
  width: 240px;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 56px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 20px 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  }
}
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 bg-light sidebar d-none d-lg-block">
  <a href="#" class="d-block p-3 link-dark text-decoration-none" aria-label="Sidebar">
    <span class="fs-5">Sidebar</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark">Orders</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark">Customers</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Content Area -->
<div class="container-fluid main-content">
  <div class="row">
    <main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
      <div class="pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
        <h1 class="h2">Content Area</h1>
      </div>
      <h4>Main</h4>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




There is no id of sidebar on the element, only a class of sidebar.

As @l3l_aze states, the sidebar is missing the ID, but even with it, I'm unsure if this works.  The collapsible element should be inside the navbar as seen in the BS documentation.  You would be better off with a BS Offcanvas component.

@l3l_aze It doesn't work, after I added the id="sidebar" to the sidebar element.

your sidebar is a class, not an id, so instead of document.getElementById you should probably use document.querySelector instead

Why reinvent the wheel? BS has an offcanvas component.


I added another button in the navbar, other than the navbar-toggler which is meant for mobile responsive manipulation for the navbar. It is in this button that I added the onclick="toggleSidebar()"

I added two classes, show and hide in the CSS.

I removed the d-lg-block class from the sidebar.

Added id="sidebar" to the sidebar element to be identified by ID.

In the toggleSidebar function, when I add hide I remove show from the classList and vice versa.


You can see the working code below:


function toggleSidebar() {
  let sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
  if (sidebar.classList.contains('show')) {
    sidebar.classList.remove('show');
    sidebar.classList.add('hide');
    console.log('show')
  } else {
    sidebar.classList.add('show');
    sidebar.classList.remove('hide');
    console.log('hide')
  }
}
.sidebar {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
  width: 240px; 
}

.show {
  display: inline !important;
}

.hide {
  display: none !important;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 56px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 20px 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  }
}
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" 
      data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" 
      aria-controls="navbarNav" 
      aria-expanded="false" 
      aria-label="Toggle navigation" >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    
    <button class="btn btn-white shadow" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> Change
    </button>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class=" bg-light sidebar show" id="sidebar">
  <a href="#" class="d-block p-3 link-dark text-decoration-none" aria-label="Sidebar">
    <span class="fs-5">Sidebar</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark">Orders</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark">Customers</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Content Area -->
<div class="container-fluid main-content">
  <div class="row">
    <main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
      <div class="pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
        <h1 class="h2">Content Area</h1>
      </div>
      <h4>Main</h4>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




Why reinvent the wheel? BS has an offcanvas component.
